# Conditional cumcount with reset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I am trying to create a cum count column that counts the instances of a boolean variable, but resets to zero when it encounters a zero in the boolean variable. I am looking for a conditional cumcount.

I have posted my code (it works) of an initial stab that I took at this issue. However, I am looking to see if anyone has something more efficient as the loop used in my solution my be slow in large dfs

```
def counter(series_converted_to_a_list):
    counter = 0
    counter_list = []
    # loop through the list and count
    for i in range(len(series_converted_to_a_list)):
        if series_converted_to_a_list[i] > 0:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 0
        counter_list.append(counter)
    return counter_list

# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'bool': [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]})

# convert the boolean column to a list
bool_series_converted_to_a_list = list(df['bool'])

# use the function
counter_list = counter(bool_series_converted_to_a_list)

# convert the list into a column in the sample dataframe
df['counter_list'] = counter_list
df
```

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or [table formatting](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: What have you tried? For example, do you know how to [get consecutive groups](/q/40802800/4518341)?

Comment: Thank you @wjandrea for helping me navigate the community etiquette! I hope the modifications have resolved the issues you pointed out.

Comment: Asking to improve existing code is a better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: @CPlus Not necessarily. Code Review is for an all-around review, but OP's only asking about performance, which is on-topic for Stack Overflow, though [it should probably be more specific](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412901/4518341), like say, how to accomplish the same thing using vectorized Pandas methods (which mozway's answer provides). I'd also make the title more specific, like say, "How do I do a cumcount in Pandas but reset the count on zeros?"

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to convert the column to a list. Just loop over the elements directly, like `def counter(bools): ... for b in bools: if b > 0: ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) after masking the 0s and setting a custom grouper on all 0-starting groups, and finally restoring the 0s with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bool': [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]})

m = df['bool'].eq(1)
df['cumcount'] = (m[m].groupby((~m).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
                  .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
                 )
```

Or, maybe simpler, using a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) which will ensure that 1 always starts on the first 1 per group:

```
m = df['bool'].eq(1)
df['cumcount'] = m.groupby((~m).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    bool  cumcount
0      1         1
1      0         0
2      1         1
3      1         2
4      1         3
5      1         4
6      1         5
7      0         0
8      1         1
9      1         2
10     1         3
11     0         0
12     0         0
13     1         1
14     1         2
15     1         3
```

Answer (score -1):

I've created a df similar to your input and build the following:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = {'booleanvar': ['1','0','1','0','1','1','1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
df

for idx, entry in df.iterrows():
 if idx == 0:
  if entry['booleanvar'] == '0':
    df.loc[idx , 'result'] = '0'
  if entry['booleanvar'] == '1':
    df.loc[idx , 'result'] = '1'

 if idx > 0:
  if entry['booleanvar'] == '0':
   df.loc[idx , 'result'] = '0'
  if entry['booleanvar'] == '1':
   df.loc[idx , 'result'] = int(df.loc[idx-1 , 'result']) + 1


df
```

Output:

```
  booleanvar    result
0    1             1
1    0             0
2    1             1
3    0             0
4    1             1
5    1             2
6    1             3
```